# Arrays selection in python

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

What is the most efficient way in python to select rows from a matrix with indices divisible by certain number (using numpy, torch or any)?

Example 1:

```
mat=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]
num=3
output=[[1,2,3],[10,11,12]] #Rows 0,3
```

Example 2:

```
mat=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]
num=2
output=[[1,2,3],[7,8,9],[13,14,15]] #Rows 0,2,4
```

Comment: No substitute for `mat[::num]`, on `numpy` only. It exceeds performance of `mat[::num]` on lists in thousands if not millions :)

Comment: More to the point, there is no substitute to basic research. Your questions at this stage in your studies are extremely unlikely to be earth shatteringly new.

Answer (score 0):

Let's set up an experiment! Let `a, b, c` be `1000 x 1000` matrix in `NumPy`, `PyTorch` and simple `Python` list of lists, respectively.
Using Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.00GHz CPU & Tesla V100-SXM2 GPU.PyTorch version 1.6.0 w/ CUDA 10.1:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

k=1000
a = torch.arange(k**2, device='cuda').view(k, k) #On GPU
b = np.arange(k**2).reshape(k, k)
c = [[j * k + m % k for m in range(k)] for j in range(k)]
```

Using the `IPython` built-in magic command `%%timeit` we obtain the time it takes to slice each of the trio. We take here the worst time it took out of 100000 iterations, to avoid noise from caching. We check with `num` in `range(1, 100)` and here are the results, the lower the graph the better:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ts_torch = []
ts_numpy = []
ts_lists = []
strides = range(2, 100)
for num in strides:
  t_torch = %timeit -o a[::num,:]
  t_numpy = %timeit -o b[::num,:]
  t_lists = %timeit -o c[::num]
  ts_torch.append(t_torch.worst)
  ts_numpy.append(t_numpy.worst)
  ts_lists.append(t_lists.worst)

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10,10)
plt.plot(strides, ts_torch, c='r', label='PyTorch')
plt.plot(strides, ts_numpy, c='g', label='Numpy')
plt.plot(strides, ts_lists, c='b', label='Lists')
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.xlabel('stride')
plt.ylabel('time [s]')
plt.show()
```

And the winners are (at least for this **non 100% scientific** experiment) - `NumPy` and `Lists` are head-to-head, `Lists` slicing with strides is slightly faster than `numpy.ndarray` in this setting.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you want just a vanilla python way to do it, I would recommend a list comprehension. Using enumerate lets you see if the index one of the indexes you want.

```
mat = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]
num = 2

out = [row  for i, row in enumerate(mat) if not i % num]

>>> [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [13, 14, 15]]
```

Also if you want a numpy solution you can use:

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.matrix(mat)
out = mat[0::num, ]
>>> [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [13, 14, 15]]
```

Comment: `np.matrix` is old fashioned, `np.array` (or, at least, `np.asarray`) is better.

Comment: @mathfux. `np.asarray` is a wrapper around `np.array`

Comment: Lists can be indexed the same way. Using a test on each index is extremely inefficient.